# Building a JS automated slideshow, but loop and/or setInterval instances run concurrently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am attempting to build a very simple automated slideshow from scratch, but I'm coming across some difficulty. I've built working slideshows before, but not ones that were automated. So I began building one and tried using a for loop structure or the setInterval() method to mimic a loop:

```
$(function carousel() {
    $('.slide:not(:first-child)').hide();
    var slide1 = $('.slide:first-child');
    var slide2 = $('.slide:nth-child(2)');
    var slide3 = $('.slide:nth-child(3)');
    var slide4 = $('.slide:last-child');

    function moveSlide(currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        setInterval(function () {
            currentSlide.hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);

            setTimeout(function () {
                nextSlide.show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 1000);
            }, 1000);
        }, 1500);
    }

    var arr = [moveSlide(slide1, slide2), moveSlide(slide2, slide3), moveSlide(slide3, slide4)];
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        if (i < arr.length) {
            arr[i] += 1;
            console.log(i + "=>" + arr[i]);
        } else {
            return;
        }
        i++;
    }, 1500);
});
```

Here's a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ryezee).

Unfortunately, this did not go well, and I know why. I understand that in JS, the code will continue to execute and will not wait for the information in a loop to finish if using setInterval or setTimeout. So my question is, what would be a good workaround that doesn't require using an external library or plugin? If you could try to stick as close to my source code as possible that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: The line with `var arr = [moveSlide(slide1, slide2),...` is *calling* the `moveSlide()` function immediately and putting its return values into the array.

Comment: That makes sense. But...prior to putting the moveSlide() instances in an array, I just had the loop run a specific instance of that function for every loop instance, but they would all still fire concurrently. I'll post another codepen if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. Calling `moveSlide()` will hide the specified slide and (after the timeout) show the specified next slide, but your use of `setInterval()` within that function means it will keep trying to hide the same first slide and then show the next one.

The line with `var arr = [moveSlide(slide1, slide2),...` is *calling* the `moveSlide()` function immediately and putting its return values into the array. So that means you've got several intervals all running (one per call to `moveSlide()`), and all stepping over each other trying to hide and show the same elements. Also the return value is `undefined`, so basically you've got an array full of `undefined`.

What I would suggest you do instead is something like the following:

```js
    $(function carousel() {      
        // get a list of *all* slides:
        var slides = $('.slide');
        // hide all but the first:    
        slides.slice(1).hide(); 
        var current = 0;
    
        setInterval(function() {
          // hide the current slide:
          slides.eq(current).hide(1000);
          // increment the counter, wrapping around from end of the
          // list to the beginning as required:
          current = (current + 1) % slides.length;
          // show the next slide after a timeout:
          setTimeout(function () {
             // note that `current` was incremented already:
             slides.eq(current).show(1000);
          }, 1000);
        }, 3500); // make the interval larger than the hide/show cycle
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
<div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
<div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
<div class="slide">Slide 4</div>
<div class="slide">Slide 5</div>
```

Notice that I don't need individual variables for the individual slides, I just have a single `slides` variable that is a jQuery object containing *all* of the slides. This means you can easily change the number of slides on the page without changing the JS at all.

Note that I was too impatient to get jQueryUI to work in the snippet so I've just used a simple `.hide()` and `.show()`, but obviously that isn't the important part of the code I've shown.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you. I'm embarrassed to admit that this is my first time seeing the .eq method. Will definitely use that from now on.

Comment: It's worth taking half an hour to read through the [list of jQuery functions and selectors](http://api.jquery.com/). Don't try to memorise the whole list or anything, just try to make a mental note of the functions that seem like they could be most useful to *you*.

Comment: Cool, will do. :)